# AIX Bash Compare datetime strings

Tags: bash, aix

I have two log files.

Log File "Out":

- One records a remote "request"
- Many lines, only worth tracking starts with TRX
- `TRX Sent: 02-000330408-01 Type: N Timestamp: 20130322-11474100`

Log File "Get":

- Records the "response"
- Many lines, only one worth tracking starts with PROC
- `PROC: 02-000330408-01 T/S: 20130322 11474500`

If you notice the examples, the timestamp differences should be minimal. The issue is that sometimes the remote stops responding.

I'm getting better at bash, but I'm at a loss for a good way to compare the two time-stamps. Basically what I'm looking for is:

```
if DateDiff(TRX and PROC) > 15 minutes: Do Something Amazing
```

Comment: This can be done relatively sanely with GNU date, but without that it's a bit of a pain AFAIK. Perl would do it though (with `Time::Local` which should be available).

Comment: I've been working in bash, but I know it does have Perl... I'll look into Time::Local

Comment: http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/31152-time-difference.html could help for inspiration

Comment: What is the format of the timestamps? GNU `date` can probably be told how to convert it; it looks like YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS; are the trailing two digts hundredths of a second?

Comment: @chepner yea. They are always 00, so I guess I could just cut those 2 off if need be to get `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this working, as a slight variation of my actual question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
use Time::Local;

$OUT = `tail -500 /log/out.log | grep ^TRX  | tail -1 | cut -c46-62`;
$GET = `tail -500 /log/get.log | grep ^PROC | tail -1 | cut -c28-45`;
my $Start = getDate($OUT);
my $Finish = getDate($GET);

$DiffS = ( $Finish - $Start );
$DiffM = ( $Finish - $Start ) / 60;

print "$DiffS\n";
exit($DiffS);

sub getDate {
  $Y = substr $_[0], 0, 4;
  $M = substr $_[0], 4, 2;
  $D = substr $_[0], 6, 2;
  $h = substr $_[0], 9, 2;
  $m = substr $_[0], 11, 2;
  $s = substr $_[0], 13, 2;

  return timelocal($s,$m,$h,$D,$M,$Y);
}
```

Although this isn't exactly what I asked, it's allowed me to give a difference which I can use in a shell script that's already setup to `if $I > $Diff then DO MAGICALLY THINGS`

```
#!/bin/ksh
result=$(/usr/bin/logDiff)
print $result
if $result > 60
    ...
```

Comment: Nice - but why `exit($Diffs)`? `exit(0)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You're right. I was having issues with the Bash Script while trying to figure out the right way to get the output of the Perl script into the variable... which I've since figured out. I only need the print, so the exit is actually unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to munge the timestamps into a format that (GNU) `date` can accept. So if you can get hold of GNU date on your AIX system, you can do it like this:

```
function toDateFormat() {
    local ts=$(echo "$1" | sed -E "s/$2.*Timestamp: ([0-9-]+)/\1/")

    ts=$(echo "$ts" | sed -E  "s/([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1 \2:\3:\4/g")

    echo "$ts"
}

function compareLines() {
    local ts_a=$(date -d "$(toDateFormat "$1" "TRX")" +%s)
    local ts_b=$(date -d "$(toDateFormat "$2" "PROC")" +%s)

    local diff=$((ts_a-ts_b))

    if [[ diff -le 0 ]] ;
    then
        diff="$((0-diff))"
    fi

    echo "$diff"
}

A="TRX Sent: 02-000330408-01 Type: N Timestamp: 20130322-11474100"
B="PROC Sent: 02-000330408-01 Type: N Timestamp: 20130322-11374100"

res=$(compareLines "$A" "$B")

if [[ "$res" -ge $((15*60)) ]] ;
then
    echo "Do crazy stuff!"
fi
```

Comment: I get very skittish when messing with live systems, so I always aim to not install anything that isn't there already. I think I have something working in a Perl script that returns the seconds-diff, for use in another script I'm reusing but I'll look at this (and GNU dates, which I don't think I have)